# What's the best way to mashup Google Maps with geolocated photos from one or more social networks?

Tags: .net, google-maps-api-3, twitter, mashup, google-image-search

I'm working on a proof of concept for a project, and I need to pin random photos to a Google Map.  These photos can come from another social network, but need to be non-porn.

I've done some research so far, Google's Image Search API is deprecated.  So, one has to use the Custom Search API.  A lot of the images aren't photos, and I'm not sure how well it handles geolocation yet.  Twitter seems a little more well suited, except for the fact that people can post pictures of pretty much anything.  I was also going to look into the API's for other networks such as Flickr, Picasa, Pinterest and Instagram.  I know there are some aggregate services out there that might have done some of this mash-up work for me as well.

If there is anyone out there that has a handle on social APIs and where I should look for this type of solution, I would really appreciate the help.

Also, in cases where server-side implementation matters, I'm a .NET developer by experience.

Comment: This question is better suited to [Programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/).